# Trying to rotate image while keep aspect ratio of the picture

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Basically what my project does is to fetch a picture from Database, place it into canvas, move it, zoom in and out, this this are working perfectly.

Next step is to rotate the picture and i have no idea what I am doing wrong. In the picture i described how my document looks like when the canvas is accessed. After I rotate the picture, it goes outside the canvas. My code looks like below and i have no idea what I am doing wrong. Thank you

[image]

```
function drawRotated(degrees) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(image.width*0.15,image.height*0.15);
        ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.translate(-image.width*0.15,-image.height*0.15);
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width*0.15, image.height*0.15);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not the answer you are expecting for. I didn't use your code. I hope it helps.

The main idea is to draw the image with the center in the origin of the canvas.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

var gkhead = gk;
gkhead.src = gk.src;
let w =  gkhead.width; 
let h =  gkhead.height; 
let x = -w/2;
let y = -h/2;  
ctx.drawImage(gkhead,x,y,w,h);


function translateToThePoint(p){
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.translate(p.x,p.y);
ctx.scale(.25,.25);
ctx.drawImage(gkhead,x,y,w,h);
ctx.restore();
}
  
function rotate(angleInRad, p){
ctx.save();
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.translate(p.x,p.y);
ctx.rotate(angleInRad);
ctx.scale(.25,.25);
ctx.drawImage(gkhead,x,y,w,h);
ctx.restore();
}



let p = {x:canvas.width/2,y:canvas.height/2} 
//translateToThePoint(p); 
rotate(-Math.PI/10,p);  

}
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  <img id="gk" src='https://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/cats/38088.jpg' />
</canvas>
```

Comment: Anything it's great @enxaneta ! Thank you, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: I was wrong with what I wrote yesterday. I don't need to rotate in the image center . I need to keep rotated picture again in 0,0 with aspect ratio . I have updated my question .